# Статические методы

Tags: java

Можно ли статическому методу передать аргумент в виде чего-то не статического? (Например, переменную экземпляра)

Comment: Статические методы внутри себя не зависят от конкретного экземпляра, но через аргументы ты можешь передать что угодно. Поэтому передать сможешь

Comment: Спасибо Вам больое.